# Want to run a .bat script to install multiple programs on different machines

Tags: windows, batch-file, software-distribution

Hey guys I need some help, is there a way to create a .bat script that can install multiple applications with out having to specify the user.

For example I have this:

`"C:\Users\User\Downloads\Setup\ChromeSetup.exe" /S /norestart "C:\Users\User\Downloads\Setup\readerdc64_en_xa_crd_install.exe" /S /norestart "C:\Users\User\Downloads\Setup\SlackSetup.exe" /S /norestart "C:\Users\User\Downloads\Setup\TeamViewer_Setup_x64.exe" /S /norestart`

Which works for the specified user but I have multiple machines I want to run this on locally and its just kind of a pain to have to go back in and change the user for each install. Is there a way to make this install to any user without having to specifically refer to the user?

Also I cannot use Ninite or other programs due to some of our other software not being available for those tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%USERNAME%` environment variable returns the current user, so you can just replace each `Users\User` with `Users\%USERNAME%`.

Comment: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%` could also be replaced entirely with `%USERPROFILE%`

Comment: Also some other [Windows Environment Variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) might come in handy.